Intermittent "Connection Refused" Error Between Spring Applications and Keycloak in Docker-Compose
I am encountering an issue with my Spring Boot application that uses Spring Security for JWT authentication. The application runs smoothly after a restart, but approximately 6 hours later, it starts throwing the following exception:
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for " keycloak-realm-path/protocol/openid-connect/certs": Connection reset
     at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:106) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:88) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.authentication.ObservationAuthenticationManager.lambda$authenticate$1(ObservationAuthenticationManager.java:54) ~[spring-security-core-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:565) ~[micrometer-observation-1.12.3.jar!/:1.12.3]
     at org.springframework.security.authentication.ObservationAuthenticationManager.authenticate(ObservationAuthenticationManager.java:53) ~[spring-security-core-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:323) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:224) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230) ~[spring-security-config-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
     at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
     at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
     at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
     at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
 Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtException: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for " keycloak-realm-path/protocol/openid-connect/certs": Connection reset
     at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.createJwt(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:173) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.decode(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:138) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:99) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     ... 84 common frames omitted
 Caused by: com.nimbusds.jose.RemoteKeySourceException: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for " keycloak-realm-path/protocol/openid-connect/certs": Connection reset
     at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.RemoteJWKSet.updateJWKSetFromURL(RemoteJWKSet.java:307) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.24.4.jar!/:9.24.4]
     at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.RemoteJWKSet.get(RemoteJWKSet.java:437) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.24.4.jar!/:9.24.4]
     at com.nimbusds.jose.proc.JWSVerificationKeySelector.selectJWSKeys(JWSVerificationKeySelector.java:157) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.24.4.jar!/:9.24.4]
     at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.selectKeys(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:283) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.24.4.jar!/:9.24.4]
     at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.process(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:354) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.24.4.jar!/:9.24.4]
     at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.process(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:303) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.24.4.jar!/:9.24.4]
     at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.createJwt(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:158) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     ... 86 common frames omitted
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for " keycloak-realm-path/protocol/openid-connect/certs": Connection reset
     at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder$JwkSetUriJwtDecoderBuilder$RestOperationsResourceRetriever.getResponse(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:491) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder$JwkSetUriJwtDecoderBuilder$RestOperationsResourceRetriever.retrieveResource(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:478) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.RemoteJWKSet.updateJWKSetFromURL(RemoteJWKSet.java:305) ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.24.4.jar!/:9.24.4]
     ... 92 common frames omitted
 Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for " keycloak-realm-path/protocol/openid-connect/certs": Connection reset
     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.createResourceAccessException(RestTemplate.java:915) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:895) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:730) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder$JwkSetUriJwtDecoderBuilder$RestOperationsResourceRetriever.getResponse(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:488) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.2.2.jar!/:6.2.2]
     ... 94 common frames omitted
 Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:323) ~[na:na]
     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:na]
     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803) ~[na:na]
     at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:961) ~[na:na]
     at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:244) ~[na:na]
     at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284) ~[na:na]
     at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:343) ~[na:na]
     at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:788) ~[na:na]
     at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:723) ~[na:na]
     at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:747) ~[na:na]
     at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1676) ~[na:na]
     at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1577) ~[na:na]
     at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527) ~[na:na]
     at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleClientHttpRequest.java:88) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractStreamingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractStreamingClientHttpRequest.java:70) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:889) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
     ... 96 common frames omitted

Setup:
Keycloak server
Two Spring Boot applications using Nimbus JWT token decoder
All containers are on the same Docker network
Problem:
Approximately every 6 hours, the Spring Boot applications start throwing "Connection Refused" errors when trying to communicate with the Keycloak server. Here are the specifics:
I can access the Keycloak server using wget from within the containers, indicating that the Keycloak server is up and running.
The issue resolves temporarily if I restart the Spring Boot applications, but then reoccurs after about 6 hours.
The exception message indicates a problem with decoding the JWT due to a "Connection reset" error when attempting to retrieve the remote JWK set from Keycloak.
Details:
Framework: Spring Boot
Security: Spring Security with JWT authentication
Auth Server: Keycloak
Error Timing: Approximately 6 hours after application start
Observations:
This problem seems to be related to the connection between the Spring Boot applications and Keycloak.
There are no errors indicating that Keycloak itself is down; the errors are specifically about the Spring Boot applications not being able to connect.
What I've Tried:
Confirmed that the Keycloak server is accessible from the containers at all times using wget.
Reviewed the logs for both Keycloak and the Spring Boot applications, but haven't found any clear indicators of what might be causing the connection issues.
Additional Information:
The Spring Boot applications use Nimbus JWT token decoder to communicate with Keycloak.
All containers are deployed on the same Docker network configured via Docker-Compose.
Verified Keycloak server is running and accessible.
Ensured network stability and connectivity.
Checked JWT token expiration settings.
Questions:
What could be causing the "Connection reset" error after 6 hours of uptime?
Are there specific configurations in Spring Security or Keycloak that could prevent this issue?
Could this be related to a timeout or resource exhaustion issue?
Any insights or suggestions for resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
